# mongodb indexing user-defined schemas

Tags: mongodb, indexing, saas

We are currently using MongoDB to allow tenants in a SaaS application to define entities that they can use in the application. We do not know know how each tenant is going to define the fields for the entities that they are creating upfront. Each entity will have a collection dynamically created for it in a separate database that belongs to the tenant.

For example, One tenant might define a Customer as First Name, Last Name, Email. Another tenant might define Shipment as Shipment Ref, Ship Date, Owner etc... Each tenant will have many entities/collections in their tenant database.

We have one field (ID) which we will always force the user to include in each entity/collection. We will index this field upfront when creating the collection.

However, how do we handle the case where we want to allow the tenant to sort/search/order/query large collections/entities *quickly* when/if the dataset becomes too large?

That is, since we do not know upfront what fields the user will be sorting/filtering/ordering by, what is the indexing strategy to use in this case with Mongo?

Comment: what about db.collection.ensureIndex() http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.ensureIndex/?

Comment: How does that resolve the problem of not knowing which fields the user is going to be utilizing most? How do I know which fields I would I apply the command to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all Mongo requires you to have `_id` for each document and it indexes it automatically. You should take advantage of this and not create yet another ID field in case you require your clients to have `ID` field. I'm not sure if that's the case in your application.

What you are asking for can't have a perfect solution or even the most optimal one, but I can suggest couple options:

- Create single field index for each field in the document. Let Mongo query optimizer decide which index to use depending on query. Disadvantages - takes lots of space on disk and in memory. Makes inserts slower. Mongo can use only 1 index in condition clause, so it will not be able to use compound index. You can easily extract schema with a tool like [this](https://github.com/izmailoff/MongoDB-Schema-Analyzer). I wrote this little prototype that analyzes and prints Mongo schema.
- Let your application learn what indexes to create. Get slow queries from Mongo profiler (in Mongo log), analyze common parts (automatically?) and create indexes on most commonly used fields. That's not so easy to implement and efficiency might change with time if your client changes queries or data. Application will be slow in the start until it learns about itself :).

Comment: The ID field that I was referring to is not an actual ID, but more like an entity ID that is made visible to the user for application purposes. It is as you noted, a requirement for the application. Thanks for suggesting some solutions Aleksey.

Answer (score 0):

Would just like to emphasize in choosing your design that the ID and not _id field you mention is actually some unique entity identifier then you are better of putting this in _id.

The reason here is that the performance trade-off for using another unique index over the required _id is a considerable overhead. Thinking about this, since _id is required it is the first thing that MongoDB looks for when determining which index to use. Otherwise consider a compound _id field containing your entity information and some other useful uniqueness.

As for the user defined fields, which is kind of the essence of mongo documents, for my money I would make it part of the API to set up indexes as required. Depending on the type of searching that is happening you'll probably want compound indexes and generated queries that make sense to these.

Simply indexing every field will probably have limited use as only one index is going to be picked for the find anyhow, and the query optimizer is going to try all of them. As has been mentioned, a long option could be to set indexes according to the usage patterns. But it could take some work to do.